# jquery accordion drupal 6 id problem

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am using jquery accordion (v.1.8). When I use prefix for div creation id is missing i.e.

```
$form['container'] = array(
  '#prefix' => '<div>',
  '#attributes' => array('id' => 'accordion'),
  '#suffix' => '</div>'
);
```

I cant see any id = "accordion" in DOM
plus if I use this method below:

```
$form['container'] = array(
  '#prefix' => '<div id = "accordion">',
  '#value' => t('&nbps;'),
  '#suffix' => '</div>'
);
```

it works can you please tell me the reason since am new to drupal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because Drupal is looking for some form element to add the id to but none are found.  For instance, if you make `#type` a fieldset as in below, the fieldset will have an id of "accordian".

```
$form['container'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#prefix' => '<div>',
  '#attributes' => array('id' => 'accordion'),
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

The code above will output a DIV that contains a fieldset with an id of "accordian".  From there you could add other form elements inside the fieldset, like:

```
$form['container']['fake'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('My Textfield'),
  '#size' => 30,
  '#maxlength' => 128,
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

For more information about Drupal forms, see the [Forms API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6), it is an extremely valuable source information.

Comment: Thank you I just figure it out i was using the above code in loop and not assigning unique number to it :)